# silverlight report vs pdf

Tags: silverlight, pdf, crystal-reports

I am developing a business portal for a company, where users must register before they can login. At the end of the registration the user must have the option to download a document that is pretty much a contract to sign. This document has to be available AFTER the user has completed registration.
The document must as well be available to download at any given time.

My question is how do I do this??

I looked into crystal reports and pdf creation. But since I've never done anything like this (on a web plataform), I'm not sure what's the best approach. I have questions like:

- Is it better to build a report and convert it to pdf, or create a pdf directly?
- Should I pull all the data I need from the server and build the pdf/report on the server side (and then download the pdf) or build it on the client side?
- Is there a better way than reports?

Also in the future the application will have other kinds of reports that the user can view or download. And because I have to keep that in mind, I don't know if I should create a different project to host the reporting engine, or just integrate the reports wherever they are needed (I'm going with the 3 layered arquitecture scheme -> UI, BLL, DAL)

These are (so far) my pressing concerns on the matter. I've spent a few hours reading some forums and blogs about the subject, but couldn't make up my mind. Any help on the subject is more than welcome.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Telerik has some controls to help with this.  Their Rtf control can be exported as a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely advocate Crystal Reports if you expect further reporting requirements later on. What sort of reports do you envisage? Customer facing (invoices, confirmations etc) or more tabular/financial/statistical? If the latter I would start to lean toward SSRS.

And definitely create your report on the server side.

Comment: Honestly, the company wich the web portal is destined for is just starting to grow, and so, even they are not so sure of what kind of info thy want to present their customers later on the future, but pretty much everything you mentioned (more legal contracts, and financial reports). I think I'm going with crystal reports, otherwise I would have to create two different engines (one for reports and other just for pdf's). Thanks Lee, it really helped

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be towards using ActiveReports if you are trying to deploy it on a SilverLight environment . ActiveReports is quite flexible and will allow you to export reports to PDF, Excel,Tiff,RTF etc .

Now coming back to answer your questions:

1.Is it better to build a report and convert it to pdf, or create a pdf directly?

I think its better to convert the report to PDF as you can decide the various facets of your report and how content should go in. You will have a lot more control over the report.After you have done this , you can easily export it.

2.Should I pull all the data I need from the server and build the pdf/report on the server side (and then download the pdf) or build it on the client side?

Create the report on the server and stream it to the Client side.

3.Is there a better way than reports?

I am not sure if there is, If there is then I would be happy to learn the same.

You can get a lot of information about exporting reports in SilveLight using ActiveReports here:http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2012/05/exporting-reports-using-active-reports.html